# La « perte d’autonomie des PP au sein de formes verbales dont la cohésion ne cesse d’augmenter depuis le Moyen Âge » ?

Tags: histoire, participe-passé, linguistique, évolution

> 3° Les PP conjugués avec l’auxiliaire *avoir* pourront s’écrire dans
> tous les cas au masculin singulier.
>
> (3) La proposition 3 s’inscrit dans le droit fil de la **perte
> d’autonomie des PP au sein de formes verbales dont la cohésion ne
> cesse d’augmenter depuis le Moyen Âge**. Quand le poète de Cour Clément
> Marot préconisait en 1538 l’accord du PP avec le substantif « qui va
> devant », il légitimait indirectement l’absence d’accord avec le
> substantif postérieur et enclenchait le processus d’invariabilité
> généralisée.
>
> [ CILF « Conseil international de la langue française » et le groupe
> EROFA « Études pour une rationalisation de l’orthographe française »,
> sur [reformeduparticipepasse.com](http://www.reformeduparticipepasse.com/) ]

Peut-on expliquer de quelle manière et pourquoi les participes passés perdent leur autonomie « au sein des formes verbales dont la cohésion ne cesse d'augmenter depuis le Moyen Âge » ou plus généralement expliquer ce que la phrase signifie à l'aide d'exemples ?

Comment: Je pense qu'en parlant d'*autonomie* on sous-entend que le participe ne s'accord pas indépendamment, comme un adjectif, mais en fonction de la forme verbale dont il fait une partie.

Comment: Répondre à cette question me semble sujet à débat. La lecture de différents articles  cités dans les [liens](http://www.reformeduparticipepasse.com/pages/liens.html) peut donner une idée de ce qui était dans la tête de ceux qui avaient écrit ces mots (Wilmet est mort depuis ...).  On peut aussi [poser la question](http://www.reformeduparticipepasse.com/contact/contacter-l-association.html) aux auteurs de la pétition. (Remarque: je suis très gênée par le titre de la page donnée dans mon lien  et depuis 2014 que la pétition est en ligne ça n'a pas encore été corrigé.)

Comment: @None Le débat est omniprésent de nos jours et il ne saurait nous effrayer et si uniquement les questions qui ne font pas débat devaient être posées il serait inutile d'en poser et on s'en tiendrait à une grammaire et à un dictionnaire et j'accrocherais mes patins. Si une idée peut nous être donnée en lisant les textes dont vous parlez, quelqu'un les lira et présentera cette idée. Enfin il est plutôt fréquent que des erreurs se glissent dans des trucs web et que les personnes responsables ne soient pas outillées pour les corriger ou ne puisse le faire faire pour un ensemble de raisons etc.